# Find a quadratic polynomial that is orthogonal to both p(x) =1 and q(x) =x.

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality

Does anyone know how to solve the following question.

[image]

Comment: How might you start? What have you tried? (By the way, the answer to the question you asked is "yes, someone knows".)

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, 
and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them 
give their answers at the right level. Furthermore, please avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures
cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the set $\{1, x, x^2\}$